# Fill a JList with database entries when selecting from a ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, combobox, jlist

I'm a rookie programmer and I was trying to create a basic windowed program using Swing and a SQL database.
I managed to get the connection working and created some forms that allows the update of the database but I can't find a way to simply fill a JList depending on what option you choose from a ComboBox.
Specifically, my database has two tables (among others), one named "SERIES" and the other named "CLASS", and my GUI has a JPanel where you can choose the series from a ComboBox, which should display the corresponding classes in a JList below.

Here's my base code (I don't paste the generated variables declaration and "initComponents()" method, but simply ask if you need), followed by the current state of the concerned method:

```
package dahouetgui;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Antoine
 */
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    static Connection con = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form DahouetGUI
     * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public GUI() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        setTitle("Dahouet Case");

        initComponents();

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dahouet","root","");

            try
            {
                Statement requete1 = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultat1 = requete1.executeQuery("select * from SERIES");

                while(resultat1.next())
                {
                    jcbSer.addItem(resultat1.getString("LIBSER"));
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("SQLException " + e.getMessage());
            }

            try
            {
                Statement requete2 = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultat2 = requete2.executeQuery("select * from SERIES");

                while(resultat2.next())
                {
                    jcbSerChoice.addItem(resultat2.getString("LIBSER"));
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("SQLException " + e.getMessage());
            }

            try
            {
                Statement requete3 = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultat3 = requete3.executeQuery("select * from CLASS");

                while(resultat3.next())
                {
                    jcbClaChoiceDel.addItem(resultat3.getString("LIBCLA"));
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("SQLException " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("SQLException " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

---

```
private void jcbSerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                       
    try
    {
        Statement requete = con.createStatement();
        try
        {
            ResultSet resultat = requete.executeQuery("select * from CLASS inner join SERIES on CLASS.CODSER = SERIES.CODSER "
                                                       + "where LIBSER = '" + jcbSer.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'");
            resultat.next();
            jlsCla.setList(resultat.("LIBCLA"));
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("SQLException " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("SQLException " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

As you can see I don't quite know which kind of "set/get" to use, or even if it's the correct way to do this (I'm following the model of a TextField...). Though I've also seen things about a DefaultListModel but I don't know exactly what it does and anyway I wouldn't know how to use it.

Thanks.

PS: no courtesy allowed in here? My "hello" is automatically removed... :/

**EDIT:**
Here's the final code for my method then:

```
private void jcbSerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    javax.swing.DefaultListModel<String> dlmCla;
    dlmCla = new javax.swing.DefaultListModel();

    try
    {
        Statement requete = con.createStatement();
        try
        {
            ResultSet resultat = requete.executeQuery("select * from CLASS inner join SERIES on CLASS.CODSER = SERIES.CODSER "
                                                       + "where LIBSER = '" + jcbSer.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'");
            while(resultat.next())
            {
                dlmCla.addElement(resultat.getString("LIBCLA"));
            }
            jlsCla.setModel(dlmCla);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("SQLException " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("SQLException " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps to do what you want in a nutshell.

1. Create a [DefaultListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) object. Perhaps you wish it to be a `DefaultListModel<String>`?
2. Create your ResultSet
3. Iterate through your ResultSet in a `while (resultat.next()) {...}` loop obtaining the element(s) of interest.
4. In the loop, place that element into your DefaultListModel using its `addElement(...)` method.
5. Set your JList's model with your DefaultListModel object via the list's `setModel(...)` method.

Comment: And why did I wait so long to post here... Many thanks, it was just what I needed. :D

Now I need to dig a little into that DefaultListModel just to understand how it works.

Comment: @ButchOverflow: glad you've got things working. If you have further questions, please ask.